# Access-VBA For Loop Executes Only Once

Tags: sql, for-loop, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to measure the duration between two updates. there is already a table which keeps track of 'lastvalue', 'newvalue' and 'updatetime'. My way is to search for the entities which satisfy the conditions and assign related updatetimes to variables and then compute.
However, my for loops doesn't work they execute only once. I'm new to access-vba and use debug.prints to see how things change (they are permanent). Below is my code, thank you

```vb
Private Sub olcum()

Dim gs As Long
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim pt As Date
Dim ct As Date
Dim pc As String
Dim cc As String
Dim id As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim k As Integer
'Dim a As Index
Dim strMessage As String


Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("GecenSure", dbOpenSnapshot)
pc = "acilmasi bekleniyor"
cc = "onayda"


rs.MoveFirst
For i = 0 To (rs.RecordCount - 1)
    strMessage = "Burada: " & (rs.AbsolutePosition + 1)
    Debug.Print (strMessage)
    'Set a = rs.AbsolutePosition
    'Debug.Print (a)
    id = rs.Fields("Kimlik")
    rs.MoveFirst

    For l = 0 To (rs.RecordCount - 1)
        strMessage = "Burada: " & (rs.AbsolutePosition + 1)
        Debug.Print (strMessage)
        If (rs.Fields("Kimlik") = id) And (rs.Fields("PreviousCase") = pc) Then
        pt = rs.Fields("UpdateTime")
        Else
        End If

        For k = 0 To (rs.RecordCount - (1 + l))
            strMessage = "Burada: " & (rs.AbsolutePosition + 1)
            Debug.Print (strMessage)
        'If (rs.Fields("Kimlik") = id) And (rs.Fields("CurrentCase") = cc) Then
            'Debug.Print "rs.AbsolutePosition"
            If (rs.Fields("Kimlik") = id) And (rs.Fields("PreviousCase") = cc) Then
            ct = rs.Fields("UpdateTime")
            Else
            End If
        'Else
        'End If
        rs.MoveNext
        strMessage = "Burada: " & (rs.AbsolutePosition + 1)
        Debug.Print (strMessage)
        Next k
        'bu prosedurle 2 kere ct atıyor.

    rs.MoveFirst

    For z = 0 To i
    rs.MoveNext
    strMessage = "Burada: " & (rs.AbsolutePosition + 1)
    Debug.Print (strMessage)
    Next z

    Next l

    gs = ct - pt
    Debug.Print gs

    'Debug.Print rs.Fields("CurrentCase")
rs.MoveNext
strMessage = "Burada: " & (rs.AbsolutePosition + 1)
Debug.Print (strMessage)
Next i

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close

MsgBox "Simdiki durumlar gosterildi"

End Sub
```

Comment: I though that it may be due to "dbOpenSnapshot" but as far as I know to use "rs.AbsolutePosition", opening as Snapshot or Dynaset is required

Answer (score 5):

[rs.RecordCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-recordcount-property-dao) does not return the total number of records in a recordset; rather it returns the number of records that **have already been accessed**.

There are several options; option 3 is often considered the best, and is the method used in many Microsoft examples:

1. **rs.MoveLast** - prior to the loop; this is not a performant option
2. Query a SQL **Count** - prior to the loop, determine the number of records
3. Use a **While** or **Do** loop checking for rs.EOF
   (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb243789(v=office.12)

An example of the Do loop:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordSet("GecenSure", dbOpenSnapshot)

Do Until rs.EOF
    ' do something
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Nitpick: I would not want to do `Do While Not rs.EOF` as suggested in #3. The code sample using `Do Until rs.EOF` reads better, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a structure like this:

```
If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then ' if not completely empty
    rs.MoveFirst                ' start at the beginning
    Do While Not rs.EOF         ' while not at end

        do something
        increment i if necessary

        ' error checking if needed:
        If i > ... Or SomethingUnwanted Then Exit Do

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
rs.Close
```

Comment: Note that `rs.MoveFirst` is technically not required, especially if you've just opened it. It would make sense if you were doing multiple passes over same recordset but in 95%+ of the case, we only do one pass over the recordset. Eliminating the `rs.MoveFirst` also eliminates the need to check for BOF/EOF, cutting 3 lines and saving a level of indentation.